# SFML fails in multithreading

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfml

im new to sfml and c++.and I have a project that uses the sfml library's to draw the graphics but when I add an additional thread to my program it fails to execute the code inside the thread. this is my code:(please help me!)

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML\window.hpp>
#include <SFML\system.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

int h(sf::RenderWindow* win){
    //do something
    win->close();
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(10));
    return 0;
}


int main(){
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800,600),"My window");
    thread t1(h,&window);
    _sleep(10000000);
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens when it *"...fails to execute the code..."*?

Comment: it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Try moving `sf::RenderWindow window(...);` to `h()`.

Comment: in my real program it must be in main and I have no choice

Comment: because its a game and I should do several graphics in one moment

Comment: Why won't you just try first to see. Even though you're constrained to put `window` in `main()`, there's nothing to stop you to try doing what I've said to you.

Comment: You should not handle the drawing in more than one thread. Maybe you can elaborate on why you want to have multiple threads, games handle things differently from normal "office" GUI applications.

Comment: ok ill try it your way

Comment: it worked but isn't there any way to send a pointer?

Comment: @nvoigt what else can I use? the only thing that comes to my mind is a thread.

Comment: I'll tell you this, and it's a hard, painful, but true one: if you're just starting out in game programming then don't use threads. Hate them. They are Evil™.

Comment: :D then what should I do I am new so if u can, please link a good tutorial on this

Comment: Right now, you could simply write the same program without any threads. Google "game loop" or read the SFML tutorials to get more info on how to do this.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/graphics-draw.php#drawing-from-threads

> SFML supports multi-threaded drawing, and you don't even have to do
>   anything to make it work. The only thing to remember is to deactivate
>   a window before using it in another thread; that's because a window
>   (more precisely its OpenGL context) cannot be active in multiple
>   threads at the same time.

call window.setActive(false); in your main(), before you pass it off to the thread.

And remember that you must handle events in the GUI thread (the main thread) for maximum portability.

Comment: Can't upvote this enough. Caused me days of headache.